# Sphinx Search: Wildcard for single character

Tags: sphinx

I remember in old days one could use "?" for a wildcard of only one character long. For example "H?" whould return Hi, or He. Is there an equivalent for this in Sphinx?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actully it is a `?` in sphinx too!

The main 'gotcha' is you need to use `dict=keywords`, and it does need to be a **recent** version of sphinx. (and need to enable 'substring matching' using `min_infix_len`/`min_prefix_len`

See
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-dict
that section also mentions the wildcard syntax.